# write text in new line(loop)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

i want to create a simple log file for and adding frames.
here is what i found so far.>br>
this class invoked from another class which is executed in looping, so everytime the loop end it will call this calss and this class will write a log(data created in time). But, all i got is everytime a new string written in txt file it only replace the first one.
how can i add a new string in new line without replacing the old one?
i read the `environment.newline` but i dont get it.

```
    private void logFile()
    {
        StreamWriter logfile = null;
        logfile = File.CreateText(Server.MapPath("/CCTV_Files/log.txt"));
        try
        {
            logfile.Write(String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmmss}", DateTime.Now) + " Frame added");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (logfile != null)
            {
                logfile.Close();
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: I know everybody would ask you to go for append but why not use log4net that has all the logging functionality? [Check this out](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). Its simple and elegant logging mechanism based on log4* methodology for logging.

Comment: It is @Hari But the OP wanted clarity on his situation, hence the response are lined up with AppendText. Suggesting log4net would be out of context and unwise without knowing the amount change/magnitude of testing the OP should undergo.

Comment: Try to accept the answers and respect the one who are taking efforts to answer you. Just a request. Thanks.

Comment: @JKarthik All I am doing is pointing out a way of implementing logging in case Lynx was not aware, its just giving an idea and I see no harm in that. And that is precisely the reason why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Absolutely! No issues at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx):

```
logfile = File.AppendText(Server.MapPath("/CCTV_Files/log.txt"));
```

instead of [File.CreateText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx):

```
logfile = File.CreateText(Server.MapPath("/CCTV_Files/log.txt"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use File.AppendText(), Here is [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) help

```
private void logFile()
    {
        StreamWriter logfile = null;
        logfile = File.AppendText(Server.MapPath("/CCTV_Files/log.txt"));
        try
        {
            logfile.Write(String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmmss}", DateTime.Now) + " Frame added");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (logfile != null)
            {
                logfile.Close();
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

This method is equivalent to the StreamWriter(String, Boolean) constructor overload with the append parameter set to false. If the file specified by path does not exist, it is created. If the file does exist, its contents are overwritten.

**Option 1 :** You can use StreamWriter with append as True.

public StreamWriter(
  string path,
  bool append
  )

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true)

**Option 2:** You can also choose to use File.AppendText.

Reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   string path = your file path;
   using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path,true))
           {

                    sw.WriteLine("string here");
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Open log file in append mod.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663.aspx

and this will be useful

http://roque-patrick.com/windows/final/bbl0190.html

Answer (score 0):

Why bother yourself in opening files and managing them !
Use log4net library:
[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

it is awesome, just few lines of configurations, and you are ready to have log file, full of information and details.

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Foo));

///In your method:
log.Info("Information");
log.Error("Error happened");
log.Debug("bla bla");
///etc.
```

here is a sample of log file:

```
176 [main] INFO  examples.Sort - Populating an array of 2 elements in reverse order.
225 [main] INFO  examples.SortAlgo - Entered the sort method.
262 [main] DEBUG SortAlgo.OUTER i=1 - Outer loop.
276 [main] DEBUG SortAlgo.SWAP i=1 j=0 - Swapping intArray[0] = 1 and intArray[1] = 0
290 [main] DEBUG SortAlgo.OUTER i=0 - Outer loop.
304 [main] INFO  SortAlgo.DUMP - Dump of integer array:
317 [main] INFO  SortAlgo.DUMP - Element [0] = 0
331 [main] INFO  SortAlgo.DUMP - Element [1] = 1
343 [main] INFO  examples.Sort - The next log statement should be an error message.
346 [main] ERROR SortAlgo.DUMP - Tried to dump an uninitialized array.
467 [main] INFO  examples.Sort - Exiting main method.
```

if you insist to use your own way, just use this code:

`logfile = File.AppendText(Server.MapPath("/CCTV_Files/log.txt"));`